# calling the same function when any radio button or checkbox are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some radio button and checkboxs like

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calcPrice(){
    console.log(checked!!);
}
</script>

<input type="radio" name="android" value="1">smart
<input type="radio" name="android" value="2">tablet
<input type="radio" name="android" value="3">both

<input type=checkbox name="func" value="0">push
<input type=checkbox name="func" value="0">distribute
<input type=checkbox name="func" value="0">internationalization
```

I would like to call the calcPrice anytime when radio button or checkbox clicked.

I am using jquery and I know how to call when certain button is clicked.

```
$("input[name='android']").change(function()
```

But I would like to call the same function when 'any' button are clicked.

How can I make it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you may have other input elements in the page, just use a class name to identify them. In my example, I used the class name `calc` so you can use it to define an on change event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function calcPrice(){
    console.log('checked!!'); // note that you missed the quotes here
}
</script>

<input class="calc" type="radio" name="android" value="1">smart
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="android" value="2">tablet
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="android" value="3">both

<input class="calc" type=checkbox name="func" value="0">push
<input class="calc" type=checkbox name="func" value="0">distribute
<input class="calc" type=checkbox name="func" value="0">internationalization
```

For your JavaScript:

```
$("input.calc").change(function() {
    calcPrice();
});
```

Comment: I think it is the best way, thanks.Btw is there any way to avoid add class to every input?? for example using wrapper div class. <div class="calc"><iput type=text><input type=checkbox></div>

Comment: yes you can use `$('.calc input').change(function(){/*do things*/});`

Answer (score 0):

> But I would like to call the same function when 'any' button are
>   clicked.

You can use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and add [:button](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/) selector in existing selector.

```
$("input[name='android'], input[name='func'], :button").change(function()
```

> An equivalent selector to $( ":button" ) using valid CSS is $(
>   "button, input[type='button']" ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    $("input[name='android'], input[name='func']").change(function(){

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
function calcPrice(){
    console.log("checked!!");
}

$("input[name='android'],input[name='func']").change(function()
{
    calcPrice()  ;                               
});
```