# To get when any button is checked inside a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery

according to this article
[calling the same function when any radio button or checkbox are clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978848/calling-the-same-function-when-any-radio-button-or-checkbox-are-clicked)

I can call the function anytime radiobutton's are checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("input.calc").change(function() {
    calcPrice();
});

function calcPrice(){
    console.log('checked!!'); // note that you missed the quotes here
}
</script>

<input class="calc" type="radio" name="android" value="1">smart
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="android" value="2">tablet
<input class="calc" type="radio" name="android" value="3">both

<input class="calc" type=checkbox name="func" value="0">push
<input class="calc" type=checkbox name="func" value="0">distribute
<input class="calc" type=checkbox name="func" value="0">internationalization
```

But now I can't add class 'calc' for each rows,
but I can add 'calc' on the wrapper div.
(it is because of formbuilder of symfony2)

now my code is this.

```
<div class="calc">
<input  type="radio" name="android" value="1">smart
<input  type="radio" name="android" value="2">tablet
<input  type="radio" name="android" value="3">both
</div>

<div class="calc">
<input  type=checkbox name="func" value="0">push
<input  type=checkbox name="func" value="0">distribute
<input type=checkbox name="func" value="0">internationalization
</div>
```

Is it possible to get the when any buttons are clicked ,same as before?

Comment: Move your script **under the html** for starts too, your script is not aware of the elements they are trying to  target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(".calc input[type='radio'], .calc input[type='checkbox'] ").change(function() {
    calcPrice();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(".calc :radio, .calc :checkbox").change(calcPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will fire whenever a radio input changes (such as when clicked). You could easily change this to reference all inputs instead of just radio boxes, by using `input` instead of `input[type="radio"]`.

You can access the individual checked status of the input using `this.checked`

```
$('.calc').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(event) {
    if(this.checked) {
        // Input is currently checked.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".calc :radio, .calc :checkbox").change(function() {
calcPrice();
});

function calcPrice(){
console.log('checked!!'); // note that you missed the quotes here
}
```

Please check this jsfiddle 
[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sgbangale/r52L4/)